# Facet on the result of a regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, facet

I've got an elastic index with documents which contain a "Source" field.

```js
{"Source": "/Bob/Test/SomeDir/1.doc"},
{"Source": "/Steve/2.doc"},
{"Source": "/Steve/3.doc"},
{"Source": "/Steve/SomePath/4.doc"}
{"Source": "/Steve/SomeOther/5.doc"}
{"Source": "/Steve/SomeOther/6.doc"}
```

Assuming source is `not_analyzed`, I can do:

```js
{"query": {"wildcard": "/Steve/*"}}
```

To get all Steve's documents. I'd like to be able to breakdown a count for *where* they were.

Desired output:

```js
"/Steve/SomePath": 1,
"/Steve/SomeOther": 2,
"/Steve": 2 /*Nice to have, omitting this one would be fine*/
```

So, I'm trying to use a regex facet to just pick out the bit of the source I want to facet on. I'm aware this isn't the most efficient way and we've got another idea in the pipeline using a custom tokenizer but if I can get a simple working version for now, we can improve upon it later.

```js
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": "/Steve/*"
  },
  "facets": {
    "tag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "OriginalURI",
        "regex": "^\\/Steve\\/.*?\\/.*$",
        "regex_flags": "DOTALL|UNICODE_CASE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I *hoped* this would facet on everything after `/Steve/` (assuming I can indicate which match group to use). In fact, it seems to apply only as a filter - should that *full* source be included in the facet or not - so I just get every unique source with a count of `1`.

Am I heading down the right path? If not, what's the correct/easy way to do this?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about ElasticSearch (including which regex engine it uses), but if your filter goes by distinct matches of the full regex, and you match the whole path and file name (due to the anchors), of course, you'll get counts of 1. Hence, don't match file name, but only the path: `^/Steve/.*?/` or even better (if supported), `^/Steve/[^/]*`. Also, why do you escape the first two forward slashes but not the third one?

Comment: @m.buettner re: the 3rd, you're right, it should be escaped - copy/paste mistake from my various attempts. I'll have a go with your suggestions, thanks - as you can tell, I don't know my regex-fu yet...

Comment: [This](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) should get you up to speed.

Comment: @Basic, have you taken a look at the pathhierarchy tokenizer? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/pathhierarchy-tokenizer/ Maybe that will do what you need more easily.

Comment: @Phil thanks, it's something we're aware of but unfortunately, a term facet on that would include a facet on _all_ sub-directories too - which would be potentially massive. I'm trying to get just a single level. I'd envisaged our custom tokenizer working in a similar way but splitting to eg `0/Steve`, `1/SomeDir`, etc... - so I can enforce a depth constraint as well. Unless there's a way around this I'm not aware of?

Comment: ouch, yes you make a good point. I'll be interested to see the final solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extract the part that you would like to facet on using term script:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {"OriginalURI": "/Steve/*"}
  },
  "facets": {
    "tag": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "OriginalURI",
        "script": "term.replaceAll(\"(\\\\/[^\\\\/]+)$\", \"\")"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a spin tomorrow and comment again.

Comment: Hi Igor, there do I find documentation on supported script syntax? I looked through mvel, and replaceAll doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: term is just a java String. So, you you need to check [java API spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)